# to get date dynamically exceeding 24hrs

Tags: mysql

Iam writing a query by which i should get the contents from table which are not attended even after 24hrs of it is created .Can any one please tell me how to get the contents . Right now iam using

Created_time<'+DateTime.Now.addmin(-24)+'

But this is not working .Can any one please help me out

Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: Hi! Could you post your table structure and the complete query you are using?

Comment: select a.opened_by aa,a.Reg_Time,b.EmpID bb,b.EmailID,a.Ticket_No aaa from im_ticketmaster a,user_master b where a.Assigned_Engineer=b.EmpID and Status!='Closed' and Reg_time<'+DateTime.Now.addmin(-24)+' . .. .. .                             Hi i want to get the contents on basis of ticket reg_time .unattended even after 24hrs of the reg_time

Answer (score 1):

Use the date functionality in the database only, that will save you trouble in the long run. Use a query like:

SELECT * FROM table_of_interest WHERE datediff(curdate(), created_time) > 0

As for your original DateTime.Now.addmin(-24), I would expect that to be 24 minutes in the past, rather than 24 hours, but I don't know what language you're using so I might be wrong.

Comment: JenEric i want to fire a query . So that to get the contents which are unattended (tickets) for more then 24hrs from the time of Reg_time(Registerd time) .Please have a check of my query. that is mentioned above .